# Bind mounting multiple volumes using docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have bind mounted multiple volumes to a container using docker-compose.yml. When I run df -h command by SSH into the container, it is only showing the 1st volume. But when run docker container inspect command, I can see the 2 volumes I created. Any reason for this? Below is the docker-compose.yml file.

```
services:
nginx: 
container_name: nginx
image: nginx:1.23
ports:
  - 8000:80
networks:
  - abc-net
volumes:
  - .:/app
  - ./../docs:/docs

networks: 
 abc-net: {
  name: abc-net
}
```

Comment: You should share your `docker-compose.yml` file, or a minimal version of it.

Comment: @hexbioc Added the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Although you have two mountpoints, they both are from the same filesystem. `df` by default prints one entry per filesystem, as it is meant to check the amount of free space on the disk. If you really need to see both mountpoints in the output, you can run using the `--all` option:

```bash
df -h --all
```

This also means that the volumes are mounted as you'd expect. You can verify this by checking the `/etc/mtab` file in the container, too.